# What is the runtime complexity of this K-way merge routine?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, merge, time-complexity

This appears to be O(n log(k)) where k is the width of the grid and n is the depth (assuming a smooth grid or the total number of elements in the grid if it's jagged). Is that correct?

```
public class KWayMerge {

  private int[] merge(int[][] grid) {
    return merge(grid, 0, grid.length - 1);
  }

  // O(n log k) wehre k is the width of the grid and n is the depth (assuming smooth grid)
  private int[] merge(int[][] grid, int start, int end) {
    if (end == start) {
      return grid[end];
    } else if (end - start == 1) {
      return merge(grid[end], grid[start]);
    } else {
      return merge(merge(grid, start, (end + start) / 2), merge(grid, ((end + start) / 2) + 1, end));
    }
  }

  private static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {
    int[] result = new int[left.length + right.length];
    int lPos = 0, rPos = 0, pos = 0;
    while(true) {
      if (lPos >= left.length) {
        System.arraycopy(right, rPos, result, pos, right.length - rPos);
        break;
      } else if (rPos >= right.length) {
        System.arraycopy(left, lPos, result, pos, left.length - lPos);
        break;
      }

      if (left[lPos] < right[rPos]) {
        result[pos] = left[lPos];
        lPos++;
      } else {
        result[pos] = right[rPos];
        rPos++;
      }

      pos++;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: The example code appears to be 2 way merge of the rows of a matrix. A k-way merge generally refers to a merge sort that merges more than 2 elements at a time. For example a 4 way merge (k == 4) merges 4 elements at a time using 3 compares (or a priority queue) for every element merged from a group of 4. As it reaches the end of runs, it drops down to 3 way merge, then 2 way merge, then copy of the rest of the last remaining run.

Answer (score 0):

Your complexity O(N*K*LogK)

For example you have 8 arrays of size N:

You will have following merges:
Iteration #1:

1. 12 (2*N)
2. 34 (2*N)
3. 56 (2*N)
4. 78 (2*N)

Iteration #2:

1. 1234 (4*N)
2. 5678 (4*N)

Iteration #3:
 1. 12345678 (8*N)

Totally:
you have following complexity
K/2 * (2*N)
K/4 * (4*N)
K/8 * (8*N)

Each of then = K*N and LogK count.

Total complexity will be **O(KN*LogK)**
Where K count of arrays, and `N` is a average size of array.